# Placeholders in PMySQL

Tags: php, javascript, sqlite, mysqli, sql-injection

I have seen a JavaScript - SQLite code.

```
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO files (name, filedata_id) VALUES (?, ?);', [         '"+name+"', results.insertId], nullDataHandler, killTransaction);
```

Is there any counterpart for these placeholders in PHP - MySQL that can achieve the same and protect from SQL Injection?

Comment: What is PMysql and what database you are using? The tag choice seems quite irrelevant

Comment: Sqlite is the name of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). However, you should still validate user input.

Comment: The keyword to look up is "prepared statements".